# Finding the intersection(s) between two angle ranges / segments

Tags: geometry

We have two angle ranges, (aStart, aSweep) and (bStart, bSweep), where the start is the place of the start of the angle segment in the range [0, 2π), and sweep is the size of the segment, in the range (0, 2π].

We want to find all of the angle ranges where these two angle ranges overlap, if there are any.

We need a solution that covers at least three kinds of situations:

[image: there can be a few kinds of cases]

But the number of cases increases as we confront the reality of the Devil Line that exists at angle = 0, which messes up all of the inequalities whenever either of the angle ranges cross it.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works by normalising the angles to said Devil Line, so that one of the angles (which we call the origin angle) always starts there. It turns out that this makes the rest of the procedure extremely simple.

```
const float TPI = 2*M_PI;
//aStart and bStart must be in [0, 2PI)
//aSweep and bSweep must be in (0, 2PI]
//forInterval(float start, float sweep) gets called on each intersection found. It is possible for there to be zero, one, or two, you see, so it's not obvious how we would want to return an answer. We leave it abstract.
//only reports overlaps, not contacts (IE, it shouldn't report any overlaps of zero span)
template<typename F>
void overlappingSectors(float aStart, float aSweep, float bStart, float bSweep, F forInterval){
    //we find the lower angle and work relative to it
    float greaterAngle;
    float greaterSweep;
    float originAngle;
    float originSweep;
    if(aStart < bStart){
        originAngle = aStart;
        originSweep = aSweep;
        greaterSweep = bSweep;
        greaterAngle = bStart;
    }else{
        originAngle = bStart;
        originSweep = bSweep;
        greaterSweep = aSweep;
        greaterAngle = aStart;
    }
    float greaterAngleRel = greaterAngle - originAngle;
    if(greaterAngleRel < originSweep){
        forInterval(greaterAngle, min(greaterSweep, originSweep - greaterAngleRel));
    }
    float rouno = greaterAngleRel + greaterSweep;
    if(rouno > TPI){
        forInterval(originAngle, min(rouno - TPI, originSweep));
    }
}
```